# Perl: unable to extract sibling value using Twig::XPath syntax

Tags: perl, xpath, twig

Recently I start to use XML::Twig::XPath but the module does not seem to recognize an xpath syntax.
In the following XML, I want the value of "Txt" node if the value of PlcAndNm node is "ext_1"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <Document>
    <RedOrdrV03>
      <MsgId>
      <Id>1</Id>
      </MsgId>
      <Xtnsn>
        <PlcAndNm>ext_1</PlcAndNm>
        <Txt>1234</Txt>
      </Xtnsn>
      <Xtnsn>
        <PlcAndNm>ext_2</PlcAndNm>
        <Txt>ABC</Txt>
      </Xtnsn>
    </RedOrdrV03>
  </Document>
  <Document>
    <RedOrdrV03>
      <MsgId>
      <Id>2</Id>
      </MsgId>
      <Xtnsn>
        <PlcAndNm>ext_1</PlcAndNm>
        <Txt>9876</Txt>
      </Xtnsn>
      <Xtnsn>
        <PlcAndNm>ext_2</PlcAndNm>
        <Txt>DEF</Txt>
      </Xtnsn>
    </RedOrdrV03>
  </Document>
</root>
```

I have tried whit expression **//Xtnsn[PlcAndNm="ext_1"]/Txt** but I received an error
This is the code:

```
use XML::Twig::XPath;
my $subelt_count = 1;
my @processed_elements;
my $xmlfile = 'c:/test_file.xml';
my $parser = XML::Twig->new(
 twig_roots    => { 'RedOrdrV03' => \&process_xml } ,
 end_tag_handlers => { 'Document' },
);

$parser->parsefile($xmlfile);

sub process_xml {
  my ( $twig, $elt ) = @_;
  push( @processed_elements, $elt );

  if ( @processed_elements >= $subelt_count ) {
    my $MsgId = $twig->findvalue('RedOrdrV03/MsgId/Id');
    my $Xtnsn_Txt1 = $twig->findvalue('//Xtnsn[PlcAndNm="ext_1"]/Txt');
    print "MsgId: $MsgId - Xtnsn_Txt1: $Xtnsn_Txt1\n";
  }
  $_->delete for @processed_elements;
  @processed_elements = ();
  $twig->purge;
}
```

Is there a simple way of using xpath to obtain the value?
I know that a possibility is somenthing like:

```
my $Xtnsn_Txt1 = $twig->first_elt( sub { $_[0]->tag eq 'PlcAndNm' && $_[0]->text eq 'ext_1' })->next_sibling()->text();
```

but I prefer using the simplest XPath syntax,

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I've posted something but could you give us more details on the error  you receive ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. The error returned is "error in xpath expression //Xtnsn[PlcAndNm="ext_1"]/Txt at PlcAndNm="ext_1" at c:/Perl/site/lib/XML/Twig.pm line 3641"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
my $Xtnsn_Txt1 = $twig->findvalue('//Xtnsn/PlcAndNm[string()="ext_1"]/../Txt');
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be :

```
//Txt[preceding-sibling::PlcAndNm[.="ext_1"]]
```

You can also modify a little bit your XPath expression to see if it works with :

```
//Xtnsn[./PlcAndNm[contains(.,"ext_1")]]/Txt
```

EDIT : This works fine with the original XML::XPath module :

```
use XML::XPath;
use XML::XPath::Node::Element;

my $xp = XML::XPath->new(filename => 'pathtoyour.xml');

my $nodeset = $xp->find('//Xtnsn[PlcAndNm="ext_1"]/Txt');

foreach my $node ($nodeset->get_nodelist) {
    print XML::XPath::Node::Element::string_value($node),"\n\n";
}
```

Output : `1234 9876`

Comment: the error remains "error in xpath expression ...". It seems that only a part of xpath syntax is implemented in the module

Comment: That's odd.Twig relies on XML::XPath module and it works fine with your XPath expression (see my updated answer). I've used `find` instead of `findvalue`, but it also works.I know the problem is solved but could you try with `'.//Xtnsn[PlcAndNm="ext_1"]/Txt'` in your script (`.` added at the beginning of the expression) ? If that doesn't work, the `parsefile($xmlfile)` step is a clue to investigate.

Comment: Hi, I tried but the script returns again the same error `error in xpath expression .//Xtnsn[PlcAndNm="ext_1"]/Txt at PlcAndNm="ext_1" at c:/Perl/site/lib/XML/Twig.pm line 3641`

Comment: After multiple tests, I think you're right. XPath support is partial (for both `get_xpath` and `find` methods). `string()` is the only way to catch a specific element with text. `element='xxx'`, `.='xxx'` and `text()='xxx'` don't work in XML:Twig but are perfectly valid with the original XML::XPath module. It works with @attributes though (`@xyz="xxx"`). From the doc : "XML::Twig implements a *subset* of XPath". Part relative to twig handlers : "You can use the string [...] foo[string()=~ /^duhn. So it must be the same for the `get_xpath` and `find` methods.